# How to set/get value in struct inside a struct

Tags: c++, struct

How can i access my struct to get/set value inside of it??
Here my example code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct t_TES
{
    double dTes;
}TES;

struct SAMPLE1
{
    struct TES;
};

int main()
{
    SAMPLE1 sss;
    //How can i get/set dtes value??
    sss.TES.dtes=10;
    cout<<sss.TES.dtes<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it posible to assign value like this "sss.TES.dtes=10";
and get the value like by calling this "sss.TES.dtes";
i already try to combine both -> or :: operator to get/set value but always got an compilation error.

Pardon me for my bad english, Thanks..

Comment: The error message of your compiler should show the reason (error: invalid use of ‘struct SAMPLE1::TES’). Read it and see you have a nested structure TES.

Answer (score 5):

structs in C++ don't need `typedef` or the `struct` keyword for instances, but they do need names for their members. Also, it's a case-sensitive language, so `dtes` is not the same as `dTes`. Try:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct TES
{
    double dTes;
};

struct SAMPLE1
{
    TES tes;
};

int main()
{
    SAMPLE1 sss;
    sss.tes.dTes = 10;
    cout << sss.tes.dTes << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with the `SAMPLE1` structure: The first is that you use `struct TES` when `TES` is not actually a structure (it's an *alias* of a structure). The second problem is that you have to actually declare a member in the `SAMPLE1` structure:

```
struct SAMPLE1
{
    t_TES tes;
};
```

Then you just nest the use of the dot-operator `.` (like you do now):

```
SAMPLE1 sss;
sss.tes.dTes = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. With `struct TES;`, you are not declaring a member variable. Try e.g. `TES member_name`, then you can access it with `sss.member_name` in your main. Also, you should try to use more descriptive variable names ;-)